# array of html elements wont render in next js

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, next.js

let me say I have some ts where I try to do li lists elements, pushed to array and try do display. Sample code:

```
   const MenuList = ():ReactElement => {

    const router = useRouter(),
liElements:any = [];
console.log(navRoutes)

useEffect(() => {
    for(let elem in navRoutes){
        const htmlElement = (
            <>
                <li>
                    <a
                        href={navRoutes[elem].href}
                    >
                        {navRoutes[elem].name}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </>
        )
        liElements.push(htmlElement)
    }
    
    
})
console.log(liElements,'dups')
return (
    <>
        <ul className={''}>
    {liElements.map((elem:any) => elem)}
        </ul>
    </>
)
```

}

export { MenuList }`

why {liElements.map((elem:any) => elem)}
doesnt render elements?

Comment: Why would you need an effect for that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is incorrect use of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). However in your case you don't need it, you can just write it without it:

```
const MenuList = (): ReactElement => {

    const router = useRouter(), liElements: any = [];

    for (let elem in navRoutes) {
        const htmlElement = (
            <>
                <li>
                    <a
                        href={navRoutes[elem].href}
                    >
                        {navRoutes[elem].name}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </>
        )
        liElements.push(htmlElement)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ul className={''}>
                {liElements.map((elem: any) => elem)}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

So if you wondering when and how you should use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

- Fetch data from API (or do other async code) and store result to state (e.g. using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)). You should not modify anything outside of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) scope (like you do now), it can cause unpredictable behaviour. Use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) if you wish to save [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) result!
- Modify HTML outside of react (e.g. set meta title). It is useful cause you can execute code inside useEffect only once (or specify when it will be executed using dependencies - second argument). Cause your component function can be called multiple times even during one rendering.

P. S. I am not sure what is `navRoutes` in your code :/